# Avoid global variables but keep code easy to understand

Tags: python

The following code includes some classes and functions.

```
def other_funcs(*args):
    # uses Roll and RollSet a lot
    pass
```

The code makes use of global variables to hold some parameter values.
I understand this is very bad practice and can cause many problems but it has the following desirable property:
It keeps the number of arguments for the defined classes and functions to a minimum and makes the code a lot easier to read and understand.

I have tried using a container class but I end up having to pass it's instance as an argument to every other function/class like `RollSet(rolls, param.roll_extra_width)` instead of just `RollSet(rolls)`. This seems unnecessarily redundant since the parameters will always remain unchanged after initialization.

Can someone please suggest a better way to hold the parameter values without cluttering the code with long argument lists and repeated arguments?

Comment: Can't you use params with default values?

Comment: This works. Thank you. I find it hard to think about this option because the Params class gets instantiated before the main block is run which feels strange. I don't understand how it would work when importing these functions from another file for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with

```
roll_extra_width = 2
max_roll_count = 5
```

they are essentially constants in your code and you did a proper job declaring them at the top of the module rather than sprinkling them throughout your code, aka the [*Magic Numbers antipattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  BTW, magic strings are a thing too: `if objecttype == "customer":`

However, if they are constants, you might as well capitalize them, that is the usual convention in those cases.

```
ROLL_EXTRA_WIDTH = 2
MAX_ROLL_COUNT = 5
```

Also, a **huge** part of the global variable concern has to do with shared global state on mutable variables.  These are, immutable, integers, so not a big worry here.

If you have tons of constants like this, you might want to shunt them off into a **constants.py** or the like because they will clutter up your code otherwise.  That's a matter of preference, other people may have other, better, suggestions.

Comment: That's good to know about the mutability of global variables. Thank you.

Comment: To recap what I ended up doing was to create a constants.py file, import from it and pass the constants as default parameters to any functions that use them as @Pynchia suggested. This last step improves code readability tremendously without affecting flexibility. Everyone's been really helpful. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I just want to mention that just because global variables are bad doesn't mean that there isn't a place for them. It's up to you to decide if you're willing to accept the downsides.

A container class is a great idea, and that's generally what I would use. In your particular case looking at the code, I would initialize `roll_extra_width` and `max_roll_count` within the classes `RollSet` and `Roll`. Looking at your code these are the only places where the variables are used and these classes are the ones being called repeatedly, and not the actual global variables.

Here's an example to make it more clear:

```
class RollSet(Counter):
    def __init__(self):
        roll_extra_width = 2
        max_roll_count = 5
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you. For simplicity I omitted the rest of the code and other parameters. In reality they get used in other parts of the code and so I would like to avoid defining them inside those two classes.

Comment: In which case, I would say you should either pass the variable multiple times through the parameter class you have or keep global variables. I personally would not want to keep them as default parameter values in functions as I might want to change them in the future. Let me know incase you think of a better solution.